# Reconnect socket io nodejs passport

Tags: node.js

I have a page with authentication using socketio.
Page init with

```
var socket = io.connect(URL, {
    reconnect: true,
    secure: true
});
```

When click login button I need socket to reconnect like :
socket.socket.connect() but I get

"Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined".
I'm using socket.io 1.3.

When use socket.io.reconnect(), nothing happen. My socket.io server doesn't get any connect event.

```
var io = socketio.listen(server, opts);

io.use(passportSocketIo.authorize({
  cookieParser: cookieParser,
  secret: '',
  store: sessionStore,
  success: onAuthorizeSuccess,
  fail: onAuthorizeFail,
}));
```

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
});

Edit: 
After try many way, I have to create new connection with option forceNew

`socket = io.connect(URL, {forceNew: true})`

It works, but doesn't listen old event I attached. 
So I have to rederacle event like : 
socket.on('event1', function() {})..